# Java Spring Boot Cloud Client Config error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to learn how to get config from server to client using spring cloud centralized configuration.
I have a application.yml file on server from which I want to get a few properties.

application.yml

```
logging:
  config: ${spring.cloud.config.uri}/logback-standard.xml
```

Instead of using bootstrap.properties in my client application I configured an environment.cmd file which I am calling in catalina.bat in local tomcat config folder. In the environment.cmd file I set the spring.cloud.config.uri.

catalina.bat

```
call "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\8.0.24\environment.cmd"
```

environment.cmd

```
  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://configuration-dev:80/configuration_server
```

pom.xml

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring Cloud-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

CloudConfigApplication.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class CloudConfigApplication extends SpringBootServletInitialize{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

CloudConfigController.java

```
@RestController
public class CloudConfigController {   

    @Value("${logging.config}")
    public String config;

    @RequestMapping(value="/log", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String log(){
        return config;
    }
```

}

If I am running it directly from my IDE with tomcat configured it is working but When I do maven install on the project I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.cloudConfigController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'logging.config' in string value "${logging.config}"
```

Please help me figure out how to solve this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this service `http://configuration-dev:80` is running?

Comment: I think the issue is with your yml file configuration, please use this below example to configure your yml file. https://springframework.guru/using-yaml-in-spring-boot-to-configure

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes the service is running

Comment: @Praveen Kumar the problem is not with the yml config I think because when I hit the endpoint of the controller /log in postman I am getting http://configuration-dev:80/configuration_server/logback-standard.xml which is correct.